# How to use format as an alternative to `round` to convert a small number to zero?

Tags: python, if-statement, format

There is a point in my program where I compare a number with zero and if it is zero I execute a series of commands. The number calculated should be zero for some conditions but it just comes out to be a really small number (**(-17)) instead of exactly zero. So, I am planning to use format to rectify that by making very small numbers zero. I test ran this below and this simple code did not work.

I avoided using `round` because that might hinder the precision I want in my my code.

Is there a way implement `format` so that it works how I want it to?

Here:

```
a='{:.5f}'.format(0.00000056)
print(a)
if a==0.:
  print('success')
```

output:

```
0.00000
```

Comment: `a` contains a string; you are comparing it to a number.

Comment: `if your_number < 0.00001: print('success')` ??

Comment: maybe you want this instead of doing it via string formatting https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: @Anentropic rounding off may increase error but I'll check how much does the answer deviate with this. Thanks

Comment: @Johny Mopp ya that seems like what I want to do but I do not understand why `0.1-0.1` is not simply zero in python.

Comment: it is `In [4]: 0.1 - 0.1 == 0` `Out[4]: True`

Comment: this may also be useful https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004)